# How to capture the selection from the contextmenu of mouse right click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

How to capture the selection from contextmenu of mouse right click?

Tried the contextmenu event. But it gets triggered as soon as right clicked.

```
$("input").contextmenu(function(){
  console.log("test");
});
```

How can I capture the value that's selected from the contextmenu?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to capture more than that the centextmenu was opened with the [contextmenu-method from jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/).

Comment: Do you mean the value of the `<input>` that was right-clicked? Or the value of the item selected inside the context menu?

Comment: @showdev i want to get the the value of the item selected inside the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.target` to find the textbox value like below:

```js
$("input").val('This is sample text for selection . Select One or more word . You ay see selected result on console.');
$("input").contextmenu(function(e) {
  let selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  console.log($(e.target).val().replace($(e.target).val(), selection));
});
```

```css
.clssize {
    width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='clssize' />
```

Comment: I think my question was not clear. I dont want to capture the input box value. I want to capture the value selected in the right click menu.

Comment: You can use  `window.getSelection`. Read that selected text  on context menu  is little bit tricky but it's work. See updated answer.

Comment: This seems pretty roundabout. You are getting the input value and then replacing the input value with the selection. Why not just console log the selection?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").on('contextmenu', function(e) {
      alert($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Running code url:- https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4ACC8FZUZHK

Comment: This will capture the right click event. Doesn't provide the selected value from the right clicked value.

Comment: you can use $(this).val() in alert.. I have updated the code you can see it https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4ACVHK8EUDN